# i am getting an error terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'

Tags: c++, data-structures

for my driver class that reads the input file and reverses the sequence of the input file I was getting an error on runtime:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

#include "wordStack.h"
#include "word.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    WordStack ws;

    // variables
    fstream file;
    string word;

    file.open("data.txt");

    // loops file for words
    while (file >> word){
        // creates new word
        Word w;
        w.setWord(word);
        // adds to stack
        ws.push(w);
    }

    // closes file
    file.close();

    ofstream fileOut("output.txt");

    // loops till stack is not empty
    while(ws.isEmpty() == false){
        // pops and add to file
        Word p = ws.pop();
        fileOut << p.getWord();
        fileOut << " ";
    }


    fileOut.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I expect the bug is somewhere in `Word` or `WordStack` and not in the code that is shown. Although with that said if you have a debugger you likely can have it stop at the exception. I know it will do so in Visual Studio Community.

Comment: For any help on this question you will have to add a [mcve] however most likely you want to spend some time and use a debugger to figure out what part of your code causes the exception to be thrown.